# How to pass empty value to the Object[] variable in java

Tags: java

I have a variable declared as `public Object[] institutes ;` Now i need to pass empty to this `institutes`variable . How do i do this

Comment: Not sure what you're asking or trying to do. What is meant by *passing empty to a variable*?

Comment: Do you mean initialize all elements of the array to `null` or the array itself to `null` or an array of 0 length?

Comment: Sorry i think i got the answer, i need to pass empty value so i wrote "new Object[0]' to give me empty value.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do, what do you mean by "pass empty to this"? If you clarified this you will likely get better responses.

Answer (score 4):

To declare `institutes` empty:

```
public Object[] institutes = new Object[0];
```

Note that this declares `institutes` as an empty array, which is defferent from having it `null`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a simple assignment operation as follows

```
public Object[] institutes = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you would like to *assign* a variable (since you cannot pass anything to a variable anyway), and also assuming that by "empty" you mean a non-null array of length zero, the assignment is simple:

```
class ClassWithInstitutes {
    public Object[] institutes;
}
...
ClassWithInstitutes obj = new ClassWithInstitutes();
obj.institutes = new Object[0];
```

Note, however, that setting public variables (or even making public variables assignable) is a bad practice. You would be better off with a pair of dedicated getter and setter:

```
class ClassWithInstitutes {
    private Object[] institutes = new Object[0];
    public Object[] getInstitutes() {
        return institutes;
    }
    public void setInstitutes(Object[] val) {
        if (val == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(val);
        }
        // Consider making a defensive copy here.
        institutes = val;
    }
}
```

This is not ideal, because getter allows direct access to the array, which is mutable. However, this is still better than allowing unprotected access to a public variable, because it gives you control over what is being set into your variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an empty* array of type Object, you can just initialize it like this:

```
    public Object[] institutes = new Object[0];
```

Your question was not very clear. If you could provide insight on what you mean that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by empty, I think you have two main options.
Null and new object